# Multidimensional associative array into html table

Tags: php

I'm currently learning php and I'm trying to print a multidimensional associative array in html table format and I'm having some trouble looping through each of the elements, here's the code

```
$test =array(
'One'=>array('fname' => 'John', 'lnom' => 'Dupond', 'age' => 25, 'city' => 'Paris'),
'Two' => array('fname' => 'Deal', 'lnom' => 'Martin', 'age' => 20, 'city' => 'Epizts'),
'Three' => array('fname' => 'Martin', 'lnom' => 'Tonge', 'age' => 18, 'city' => 'Epinay'),
'Four'=> array('fname' => 'Austin', 'lnom' => 'Dupond', 'age' => 33, 'city' => 'Paris'),
'Five'=> array('fname' => 'Johnny', 'lnom'=>'Ailta', 'age' => 46, 'city'=> 'Villetaneuse'),
'Six'=> array('fname' => 'Scott', 'lnom' => 'Askier', 'age'=>7, 'city'=>'Villetaneuse')
);
```

what I'm trying to do :

```
foreach($test['One'] as $key=> $value)
{
    
    echo $value;
}
```

I'm not too sure about the rest if I should use a nested foreach loop or something else to print all the keys + values ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through this array completely and turn it to an html table you need two loops - one for the main and second for inner array for example:

```
<?php

$test =array(
'One'=>array('fname' => 'John', 'lnom' => 'Dupond', 'age' => 25, 'city' => 'Paris'),
'Two' => array('fname' => 'Deal', 'lnom' => 'Martin', 'age' => 20, 'city' => 'Epizts'),
'Three' => array('fname' => 'Martin', 'lnom' => 'Tonge', 'age' => 18, 'city' => 'Epinay'),
'Four'=> array('fname' => 'Austin', 'lnom' => 'Dupond', 'age' => 33, 'city' => 'Paris'),
'Five'=> array('fname' => 'Johnny', 'lnom'=>'Ailta', 'age' => 46, 'city'=> 'Villetaneuse'),
'Six'=> array('fname' => 'Scott', 'lnom' => 'Askier', 'age'=>7, 'city'=>'Villetaneuse')
);

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>fname</th>
        <th>lnom</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>city</th>
    </tr>

<?php

foreach($test as $key => $val){
    ?><tr>
        <td><?php echo $key;?></td><?php

        foreach($val as $k => $v){
            ?><td><?php echo $v;?></td><?php
        }
    ?></tr><?php
}

?>
</table>
```

Will return:

```
#     fname  lnom   age city
One   John   Dupond 25  Paris
Two   Deal   Martin 20  Epizts
Three Martin Tonge  18  Epinay
Four  Austin Dupond 33  Paris
Five  Johnny Ailta  46  Villetaneuse
Six   Scott  Askier 7   Villetaneuse
```

Comment: Oh I see awesome, now I have a better idea on how to work with these arrays, thx

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the outer array:

```
<table>

<?php foreach ($test as $person) { ?>   

    <tr>
        <td><?= $person['fname'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $person['lnom'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $person['age'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $person['city'] ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

The variable `$person` will contain the sub array, from which you just fetch the elements you want.

If you want to output every column dynamically (not needing to write `$person['fname']` etc), then you can create a nested loop:

```
<?php foreach ($test as $person) { ?>   

    <tr>

    <?php foreach ($person as $value) { ?>

        <td><?= $value ?></td>

    <?php } ?>

    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Deal If any of the answers helped you solve your issue, please accept it.

Comment: done, I'm still new to stackoverflow and was wondering if I could accept two answers, ty again :)